# Syntactically compact & performant method to select props to check for equality in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, equality, react-props

I'm wondering how to go about selecting the props for comparison without having to repeat myself to a ridiculous degree.

Comparing all the props is too computationally expensive, but cherrypicking them like below is too development-time intensive and has many opportunities for implementation mistakes. You can see even this simplest of examples is very verbose.

Is there any library to choose the props to compare?

---

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  const {
    myObj, 
    myString,
    myBool,
  } = this.props;
  const {
    myObj: nextMyObj, 
    myString: nextMyString,
    myBool: nextMyBool,
  } = nextProps;

  if (!shallowequal(
    {
      myObj,
      myString,
      nextMyBool,
    },
    {
      myObj: nextMyObj,
      myString: nextMyString,
      myBool: nextMyBool,
    }
  )) return true

  return false;
}
```

Comment: The `return false;` at the end will never be reached. Also, this is very expensive in terms of performance as it is creating two new objects, and calling another function.

Comment: Why not just an old comparison like: `return this.props.myObj.updateTime === nextProps.myObj.updateTime && this.props.myString === nextProps.myString && ...;`. That has the best performance. Verbose is not always bad.

Comment: this is as compact and performant as it can get: https://jsfiddle.net/xdytmhe6/

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for pointing that out. I threw that in at the end without thinking. The reason I use `shallowequal` here is that I often need to compare whole objects, and I ended up stripping that from this example by the time I was done editing it. I've edited it back in.

Comment: ... `shallowequal` is already returning `true` or `false`, so no need for `if` and the two `return`s, just do: `return !shallowequal(...);`

Comment: Yes, it's just for example purposes. In reality I have additional blocks of logic.